# How to print an error string in my Angular Controller?

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I have a function inside my angular controller that starts when i click a certain button on my html page. What i want to do is, basically, to print an error string under the button once a certain condition verifies. I already have a working check for the condition, but how would i go to print a string once the condition is verified?

This is the my incomplete code, what should i put inside the boolean check?:

```
 $scope.functionName = function () {
        var  = $('#data_' + $scope.indiceSelezione).val().replace(/\//g, '');
        if (data === undefined || data === '') {
            if ($scope.response.result[$scope.index].flag === true) {

            }
            else {
              $scope.change('CONVALIDATO');
            };
```

Comment: What do you want to print? which variable? please rewrite your question with enough code and clarity.

Comment: I want to print a new variable that contains a string with the error. I want to put this variable inside my check directly, since i'm only gonna use it there. I want this variable to show on my html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign the error message in the `$scope` as follows:

```
 $scope.controlliConvalida = function () {
        var dataRendIntegr = $('#dataRendInteg_' + $scope.indiceSelezione).val().replace(/\//g, '');
        if (dataRendIntegr === undefined || dataRendIntegr === '') {
            if ($scope.response.risultatoRicercaPrimoLivello[$scope.indiceSelezione].flagInLavorazione === true) {
              $scope.errorMessage = "Your error Message"
            }
            else {
              $scope.cambiaStatoProcesso('CONVALIDATO');
            };
```

In your HTML you can just print it using interpolation {{ }}

```
<p> {{ errorMessage }} </p>
```

Comment: This works, and it already shows an error prompt under my button. Is there a way to insert the text there directly? Right now it shows the error prompt but without anything inside.

Comment: what do you mean by error prompt, can you show the image in your question?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/JvxT9Pn this is the error prompt that shows right under my button. If possible, i'd like to print the string inside it.

Comment: Nevermind, i made it work. Your suggestion helped, thank you!